# What does the "Business Rule IND-005-01" error mean when submitting my tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

I received this rejection notice in an email:

> Issue : Business Rule IND-005-01 - If Form 9465 and IRS Payment Record are present in the return, then Form 9465, 'PaymentAmt' must be equal to 'PaymentAmt' in IRS Payment Record.

Can someone tell me what it means?

Comment: It's telling you that the same value occurs in two places--but they disagree in your return.